# Removing brackets at dataframe or list [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, list

I'm tryin to remove bracket and split a part of a string that duplicated in column 0 when I create a new `DF` or `list` with this two columns from a csv:

```
indice Password Status     Priority Arrive time        Call time    Begin        End      Standby Time  %TME    TME         time_raw
0   1   NB0001  Atendida    Normal  28/11/2022 08:01    08:02:24    08:02:42    08:13:54    00:01:19    100,00% 00:01:19    00:00:02
1   2   NB0002  Atendida    Normal  28/11/2022 08:01    08:03:54    08:04:21    08:12:33    00:02:20    127,85% 00:01:49    00:00:03
2   3   NB0003  Atendida    Normal  28/11/2022 08:03    08:03:59    08:05:23    08:22:21    00:02:11    112,29% 00:01:57    00:00:04
3   4   NB0004  Atendida    Normal  28/11/2022 08:15    08:04:19    08:05:15    08:13:59    00:01:12    68,25%  00:01:46    00:00:05
4   5   NB0005  Atendida    Normal  28/11/2022 08:16    08:18:46    08:20:21    08:27:19    00:02:51    144,18% 00:01:59    00:00:06
```

```
df = ['arrive time'] = 
28/11/2022 08:01
28/11/2022 08:01
28/11/2022 08:03
28/11/2022 08:15
28/11/2022 08:16
28/11/2022 08:17
28/11/2022 08:20
```

and

```
df2 = ['standby time'] = 
00:01:19
00:02:20
00:02:11
00:01:12
00:02:51
00:06:22
00:06:55
```

I tried different ways to bring it and append the two columns in one `DF` or `list` like code below with one column for `DF1`and `DF2` at the same `DF` or `list`

```
squares = [[]]
x = dados[["arrive time"]]
y = dados[["index"]]
date_arrive = dados['arrive time']
date_arrive = pd.to_datetime(date_arrive, dayfirst=True)
for i in range(len(x)):
     TE = x["wait time"]
     hours = str(x["arrive time"][i]).replace("    ","").split(":")
     hoursTMEX = str(x['arrive time'][i]).replace("    ","").split(":")
     TMEX = int(hours[0].replace("0  ","")) * 3600 + int(hours[1]) * 60 + int(hours[2].replace("\n1  00",""))
     TEX = int(hoursTMEX[0].replace("0  ","")) * 3600 + int(hoursTMEX[1]) * 60 + int(hoursTMEX[2].replace("\n1  00",""))
     squares.append([[date_arrive], [TEX]])
     data_df = pd.DataFrame(squares)
     data_df = data_df
```

**RESULT (Code above):**

```
0   None    None
1   [[2022-11-28 08:01:00, 2022-11-28 08:01:00, 20...   [79]
2   [[2022-11-28 08:01:00, 2022-11-28 08:01:00, 20...   [140]
3   [[2022-11-28 08:01:00, 2022-11-28 08:01:00, 20...   [131]
4   [[2022-11-28 08:01:00, 2022-11-28 08:01:00, 20...   [72]
```

I need it like that:

```
0|  None               | None   |
1|  2022-11-28 08:01:00|    79  |
2|  2022-11-28 08:01:00|   140  |
3|  2022-11-28 08:01:00|   131  |
4|  2022-11-28 08:01:00|    72  |
...
```

PS: I tried to append this two infos `squares.append([[date_arrive], [TEX]])` out of the loop but returns me only one line, probabilly I'm not going right way.

I'll be pleased if someone could help me to remove the repeated string in column 0 and help me remove these brackets in the two columns.

Comment: Are the dataframes aligned?  Also what you want is not so clear, can you provide the indices/constructors of both dataframes and of the output? and explain the logic in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I founded is when `Appending` the list like that:
`squares.append([[date_arrive], [TEX]])`

was missing [i] iterator from loop (for)

`squares.append([date_arrive[i], TEX])`